# Make div width max of two values?

Tags: html, css

Consider the basic HTML below:

```
<body>
    Random HTML content
    <div class="container">
        <!--Some content loaded via ajax or the like -->
    </div>
    Other random HTML content
</body>
```

I want the width of the "container" div to be the MAXIMUM of three potential values:

1. 100% of the window
2. 1024px (for best visual appearance)
3. the width of the content

I have been able to accomplish #1 and #2 by using the CSS properties width:100% and min-width:1024px. I can also accomplish #2 and #3 by setting display:inline-block and min-width:1024px. However, I haven't been able to get all three: if I add in the width:100% to the display and min-width properties, it overrides the child content sizing effect of the inline-block display and gives me only 100% width, even when that means the content overflows.

I know I can hide overflow or give the div itself scrollbars, but what I want is for the div to expand as needed, or to the full width of the window, whichever is greater - but never narrower than 1024px.

Edit: Note that the content loaded in the div may be less than 1024px. The div itself, however, should never be less than that, as it would no longer blend nicely with the look and feel of the rest of the page.

Comment: @AramilRey Theoretically, yes it is - I suppose I could write a script that runs on document ready which checks the width of the div, and if it is less than 100%, sets it to 100%. Or some such approach. Of course, a pure CSS solution would be "cleaner" :)

Comment: so my understanding is "the width of the content" will never get smaller than 1024?

Comment: @sdcr Sorry to be unclear about that. No, the width of the content may well be less than 1024px, it's just for general aesthetic reasons that I don't want the div itself to get any narrower than 1024 px. There are other elements on the page, and if that div gets narrower then it starts looking weird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding another div on top of first one:

```
<div class="container2">
    <div class="container">
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.container2{min-width:100%;  display:inline-block;}
.container{min-width:1024px; width:100%;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/om10t3gn/4/

Comment: This appears to work perfectly. Interesting how some things can turn out to be so simple...

Answer (score 3):

You can augment your second proposal with a virtual pseudo-element to achieve the dimensions you want without using javascript

```
        .container {
            min-width: 1024px;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .container::before {
            width: 100vw;
            display: block;
            content: ' ';
        }
```

Basically, it's adding a zero-height element to the top of your container that has the same width as your viewport, which is 100% of the width of `<body>`.  So it adds #1 to your existing solution that already achieves #2 and #3.

And it doesn't use any javascript, and will stay correct with resizes.

Comment: Works perfectly under Firefox on my mac. Under Safari, however, the content loads properly, but doesn't resize if the user then resizes the window. I'll have to try a couple more browsers - may just need some tweaking for safari or something.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to Safari to test it, but please keep us posted if you discover anything.

Answer (score 2):

I am not very skilled with CSS, but I think I have a solution for this problem.
To have a max-width in pixels and a max-with in percent at the same time, you could first calculate the width with the clamp-method (this includes the first of your two max-widths) and then add a normal max-width. The clamp-method is relatively new and not supported by old browsers unfortunately.

```
<div class='container'></div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
width:clamp(400px,250px + 25vw,100%);
max-width:700px;
}
```

This should set a max-width both at 100% and 700px.
I have tested it on a notebook with Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript to pick the largest value, use jQuery to assign that value to the width of the container div.

```
    var window_width = $(window).width();
    var container_width = $('.container').width();
    var default_width = 1024px;

    var max_width = Math.max(window_width, container_width, default_widht);

    $('.container').css('width', max_width);
```